# Changing the Trashcan icon in the dock

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it possible to write a program for Mac OS X that monitors the trashcan and changes the icon dynamically when you fill the can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. [Candybar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) does it. I expect that rather than dynamically changing the icon, they just register a new 'empty' and 'full' icon with the Dock process.

Answer (score 0):

[Panic's Candybar](http://panic.com/candybar/) lets you customize system icons (including the trash), so it must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The NSDockTile class allows you to make changes to your application's icon in the dock:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The Trash is actually a hidden folder in the user's home folder called `.Trash`
I guess you could monitor whether or not it's empty by periodically finding the size of the folder. Or you could run `ls` using NSTask, and find out whether there are any files left in it.